# How to host asp.net application with ms access database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, web-hosting

I am working on one web application in which there is one ms access database instead of ms sql server database.

I had worked on ms sql server database and also hosted on web hosting server.but i never worked with ms access database.

I just want to know can i host web application with ms access database? if yes then how?

Comment: Google it and try please. Please post here if you hit any roadblocks in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can host ASP.NET application using MS Access you just need to give path of your database file in connection string while connecting to database like this.

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\MyProject\Data\MyDB.accdb;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

and then query the database just like you are doing with SqlServer

Comment: ok. but this can be done in local pc. but i want to host over web hosting server. then how can i give data source  path?

Comment: you need to put database file on server where your asp.net application is hosted.